# Paypal Express Checkout for my developing wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal

Situation: I am developing a wordpress plugin where on `http://example.com/edit-order`, customer can upload an image, modify the image, resize it and have it printed by the printer. The user will then need to pay for the good base on the the final image size. For the purpose of shortest workflow, I would like to have the "checkout" button on the same page as well.

I was hoping to integrate paypal as the payment gateway, and I believe the paypal express checkout button integration would be the 'easiest'. I have read the paypal document [here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/). What really confused me is it can integrate for client-side REST or server-side REST, and even after reading all the example codes and example, I don't know how to integrate into my plugin.

For client-side REST: I know I can callback on 'onAuthorize' to redirect to a pre-defined page to confirmed payment on server-side, but how do I pass the success payment detail back to the server? and more importantly, how do I know the payment detail passed back is from paypal and genuine instead of being sent from malicious site?

For server-side REST: this make more sense to me to call the paypal API from server side, but how do I pass the payment amount and order detail from `edit-order` page to the `create-payment` page? from the example code

```
    var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = 'https://my-store.com/paypal/create-payment';
    var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'https://my-store.com/paypal/execute-payment';

    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        client: {
            sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxx',
            production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
        }

        payment: function() {
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function(data) {
                return data.id;
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data) {
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID:   data.payerID
            }).then(function() {

                // The payment is complete!
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            });
```

since `paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL)` seems to accept only one argument, how to pass along the order detail in order to create the payment?

FYI, I have used stripe SDK and API before and they were so straight forward...I just don't understand how paypal express check out is done! Especially for client REST which makes no sense to me...why would anyone want to client REST which finish the whole process in client side and pass nothing back to server to determine if the good is paid for? What did I missed and did not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For client-side REST: I know I can callback on 'onAuthorize' to redirect to a pre-defined page to confirmed payment on server-side, but how do I pass the success payment detail back to the server? and more importantly, how do I know the payment detail passed back is from paypal and genuine instead of being sent from malicious site?

You're correct that there's no 100% reliable way to do this. The recommended approach here would be to pass the paymentID and payerID back to your server and to make the call there the to paypal REST api to validate the amounts.

> For server-side REST: this make more sense to me to call the paypal API from server side, but how do I pass the payment amount and order detail from edit-order page to the create-payment page? from the example code

The way I'd recommend is:

1. Do `execute()` in onAuthrorize
2. Redirect the page
3. Make a server-side call to get the payment details

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-payments-api/show-payment-details/

You also have the option of building a single page app, and showing the details returned by client-side `execute()` on the same page

> since paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL) seems to accept only one argument, how to pass along the order detail in order to create the payment?

You can actually pass a second parameter, which will be passed to your server as key-values:

`paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL, { foo: 'bar' })`

`paypal.request.post` is actually just a wrapper to make ajax calls more easily.

> why would anyone want to client REST which finish the whole process in client side and pass nothing back to server to determine if the good is paid for?

You should still do server-side validation to make sure the item is paid for. The client side integration just makes it simpler to create and execute the payment.

---

One thing to note -- both the client and server-side integrations use the same REST api. So there's nothing stopping you from using both in conjunction with each other. The client-side calls just make it a little bit easier to do some of these calls without additional server-side logic.

Comment: Great answer! One more question, can you redirect me to the document for their express checkout JavaScript? The "document" I found are just the demo and example without detail on method and function the JavaScript/library actually provides

Comment: The code itself is hosted here and there are a few more examples on that repo: https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout -- it's still missing full api docs though for everything the javascript offers.

Comment: I knew it... without knowing what parameters/arguments these functions take and what is being return hinder me so much.... any outdated documents I may take a look at to at least have some ideas? (Ps I know I can always dig into the source... but the point of using a sdk is so I don't have to understand all the logic behind... and frankly I am still new to programming and these may overwhelm me)

Comment: Anything specific you're hoping to do? I might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: With your suggestions I guess I will adapt the full client side REST, and pass the payment id to server side through ajax after execution to check if payment was indeed paid for, ajax back to client javascript and redirect to success-payment page. With you information that the JS is using the same API as the PHP, I guess I can work out what is being returned from the execute() and how to pass it back to server...let me try to implement it and if I really cannot figure it out then I will trouble you again! Thanks a lot!